# express generate json file on the fly

Tags: file, express

I have a rest api (expressjs) which handles user personal records.
I want to create a route that will allow a user to download all of its records in a json file(the file should be generated on the fly and not be stored on the server_.I found the following gist:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.contentType('text/plain');
  res.send('This is the content', { 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=name.txt' }); 
});
```

Which I modified to this:

```
router.get('/records/export', validateToken, async (req, res, next) => {
        const id = res.locals.user;
        try {
            const user = await User.findById(id).exec();
            const {
                records
            } = user;
            res.contentType('json');
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.send(JSON.stringify(records), {
                'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=record-backup-${user.email}`
            });
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    });
```

However when I try to hit that endpoint I get the following error
`RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code:`

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it the status code like this:

```
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(records), {
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=record-backup-${user.email}`
 });
```

Comment: see my updated answer.I included a screenshot of the error

Comment: Do you need the "next" parameter for something? Maybe an exception occurs in the "try" block so the "catch" gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out what was wrong with my code.
`res.send` accepts only one argument.So I used res.set to set content-disposition header and my working code is this:

```
router.get('/records/export', validateToken, async (req, res, next) => {
        const id = res.locals.user;
        try {
            const user = await User.findById(id).exec();
            const {
                records
            } = user;
            res.contentType('application/octet-stream');
            res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=record-backup-${user.email}`)
                .status(200).send(JSON.stringify(records));
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    });
```